# Self calling PHP form doesnt work after "Use URL rewriting" is set to Yes in Joomla 2.5

Tags: php, url-rewriting, joomla2.5

I have a self calling PHP form in a Joomla article. This article is then linked with a Menu item.

```
<form class="form-inline" name="test" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post" >
```

Before using "Use URL rewriting" the PHP form was working fine. i.e "Use URL rewriting" was set to NO.

After setting the "Use URL rewriting" to Yes the PHP self calling form doesnt submit. When the submit button is pressed, the browser throws the user to the homepage.

I want to use "Use URL rewriting"->Yes as it makes the website SEO friendly while also using the PHP self calling form. Is there a way to do both ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check the output of <?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?> with and without URL rewriting - see if there is a difference. If not, it may be worth researching how Joomla rewrites URLs

Comment: Without URL rewriting
Browser Address bar domain.com/index/index.php/test
Echo result /index/index.php/test

With URL rewriting
Browser Address bar domain.com/index/test
Echo result /index/index.php/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this using **`$_SERVER['SCRIPT_URL']`**, but is possible that other $_SERVER array elements could do the trick too, such as `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`,
`$_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']` and `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_SCRIPT_URL']`.

If not help, add this to your code

`var_dump($_SERVER);`

to show all the array elements and looking for the right ones.